# Failed to find by foreign key

Tags: spring-boot

I want to display all the rooms belong to the hospital of the current user

## Class Room :

```
@Entity(name = "rooms")
@Table( name = "rooms",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "roomNumber")
        })
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long idRoom;

    private  String roomNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idhospital")
    private Hospital hospital;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "room")
    private Set<Bed> beds;
 
  //getter and setter
```

## Repository :

```
 @Query("SELECT rm from rooms rm where rm.hospital=?1" )
      List<Room> findRoomsByHospital(Hospital hospital);
```

## Service  :

```
List<Room> getRoomsByHospital(Hospital hospital);
```

ServiceImpl :

```
  @Override
    public List<Room> getRoomsByHospital(Hospital hospital) {

        return roomRepository.findRoomsByHospital(hospital);

    }
```

## Controller :

```
     @GetMapping("/display/room")
public ResponseEntity<List<Room>>  getRoomsbyHospitalId(Authentication authentication) {
    logger.info("Getting all RoomsByHospitalId  from room table...Call getRoomsbyHospitalId ");


     // to get the current user
      Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName());

      // to get the id of the hospital of the current user
      Hospital hospital = user.get().getHospital();


    logger.info("Data extracted from room table...");
    //return ResponseEntity.ok(HospitalRooms);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(roomService.getRoomsByHospital(hospital), HttpStatus.OK) ;
}
```

I had this error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzApo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbFRO.png)

=========================================================================

help please!

Comment: Did you make sure that your authentication object is not null? Otherwise authentication.getName() will throw an NPE as you try to get an property from NULL. Further: is the repository injected correctly or could at be null? Set a breakpoint and check if authentication and repository are not null. Side note: check the optional user if not empty before invoking get on an optional.

Comment: Not null I'm testing with my frontend I have login user

Comment: What about the repository? Based on your screenshot the line just contains the repository and the authentication object which both may be null and produce a NPE

Comment: authentication object Not null and the repository I changed the query like this:

Comment: @Query(value="select * from rooms where rooms.idhospital=?1", nativeQuery=true)

Comment: Ihave this error:

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]

Comment: This exception is the result of another error. Have you tried to debug the steps of your code to determine which part is the exact problem?

Comment: when I debug Controller I had this : "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "No message available",

Comment: May be the repository return Null  (may Be the query is wrong)

Comment: Then you would get an Optional.Empty and the line where you invoke get() will lead to an NPE

Comment: the query return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solution in to add this notation @JsonIgnore here

```
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idhospital")
    private Hospital hospital;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just NullPointerException doesn't really show where It's comming from, to help you debbug in the **application.properties** write the following:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

When running now It's going to show you how hibernate is handling your queries where are the null Objects or if it's getting the error before that. Here you are getting just an Id and It's being instance a HospitalModel

```
   // to get the id of the hospital of the current user
          Hospital hospital = user.get().getHospital();
```

Try just doing that instead:

```
 Long hospital = user.get().getHospital();
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed